# SQL query where clause is ambiguous

Tags: sql

Im trying to query my data with the same user_id and error occurs.

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
JOIN users 
WHERE user_id = 1 
AND user_id = 1;
```

Error encountered was:

> Column 'user_id' in where clause is ambiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an explicit `JOIN` with `ON`:

```
SELECT c.*, u.*  -- you should really explicitly list the columns
FROM contacts c JOIN
     users u
     ON c.user_id = u.user_id
WHERE u.user_id = 1 ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Both the table you're pulling `FROM` and the table you're `JOIN`ing have a field called `user_id`. Specify which table you want to compare the `user_id` from:

```
SELECT * 
FROM contacts 
JOIN users 
WHERE contacts.user_id = 1
AND users.user_id = 1
```